# Visual Studio 2012 and MS Sql Server 2012 - connect with Server Explorer

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, server-explorer

I have a problem establishing connection with Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with MS SQL server 2012 Express. Everything is on local machine.

You can see screen shot here - http://s16.postimage.org/4gvo7r5id/se_prob_ss1.png

**With System.Data.SqlClient** and SqlConnection.Open() everything **work** fine I'm able to connect and execute SQL scripts (with and without Windows Authentication).

What I tried so far:

- I checked in MS SQL Management Studio in Conncetions "Allow remote
  connections to this server" (Checked)
- In SQL Server Configuration Manager on my SQL server TCP/IP protocol is enabled
- I tried to connect with turned off firewall and antivirus protection
- I tried with new Logins (with System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection it work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the picture, the server name you are connecting to appears wrong. You indicated you installed SQL Express; it has a default instance name of SQLEXPRESS. So the server you are connecting to should be:

```
MILLENIUM\SQLEXPRESS
```

instead of just MILLENIUM.

Comment: Thank you, I was mislead from the Server Explorer wizard. In my case was MILLENIUM\MILLENIUM It's strange that with System.Data.SqlClient the connection string is in this format .\\MILLENIUM

Comment: The . means the database is local to the machine the app is running on. The two backslashes (\\) are because it's an escaped c# string. It is the same.