# sql 2012 express and vs2012

Tags: c#, sql

How can I connect Visual Studio 2012 to SQL Server 2012 express on localhost. My server name :

```
HACEGAN\SQLEXPRESS
```

what must I write to my connection string i.e

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\HACEGAN.SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Register;User ID=sa;Password=123");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write your *server name* to your `Data Source` part ?

```
Data Source=HACEGAN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Register;User ID=sa;Password=123
```

Change your

```
localhost\\HACEGAN.SQLEXPRESS
```

to

```
HACEGAN\SQLEXPRESS
```

Check out: [Visual Studio 2012 and MS Sql Server 2012 - connect with Server Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437480/visual-studio-2012-and-ms-sql-server-2012-connect-with-server-explorer)

You can find *Server Explorer* in `Visual Studio 2012 -> View -> Server Explorer`

Comment: I write HACEGAN\SQLEXPRESS but an exception coming unsder thisline after '\' that is : Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: @SelçukluEbrar Check out this topic http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

i think you write it directly,

```
Data Source=HACEGAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Register;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be specifying both a servername & localhost. One or the other.

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HACEGAN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Register;User ID=sa;Password=123");
```

Please note the @ symbol to prevent escaping issues.

Answer (score 0):

If your sql server is also a default instance, you can use `.` notation:

```
Server=.;Database=Register;User Id=sa;Password=123;
```

If non-default, use `.\SQLExpress`.

Answer (score 0):

All other answers in this post are correct, but in your case you should write:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HACEGAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Register;User ID=sa;Password=123");
```